# How to hold axis constant with Animate

Tags: plotting, animation

So I am trying to use Animate for my 3D Plot, to see how the function changes with respect to time. But for some reason the z axis keeps rescaling such that the function appears to be constant (but isn't actually). 
My question is: Is it possible to fix the axis? if yes, how?
Here is my code:

```
uh[x_, y_, t_] = 1 + E^(-2 t)*Sin[x]*Sin[y];
Animate[Plot3D[uh[x, y, t], {x, -2 π, 2 π}, {y, -2 π, 2 π}], {t, 0, π}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `PlotRange -> {0, 2}` in `Plot3D`?

Comment: I tried but I feel like the result should be different... But I dont see what would be wrong. Any idea?

Comment: just posted what get in Version 9.0.1.0 (Windows 8) when change the `PlotRange`.

Answer (score 3):

```
uh[x_, y_, t_] = 1 + E^(-2 t)*Sin[x]*Sin[y];
Animate[Plot3D[
  uh[x, y, t], {x, -2 π, 2 π}, {y, -2 π, 2 π}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 2}, BoxRatios -> 1, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {t, 0, π}, 
 AnimationRunning -> True, AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward]
```

[image]